# Linux c programming fifo fails with no reason

Tags: c, linux

I have 2 different programs that I want to connect through a FIFO, and for some reason it isn't working right. The call to `mkfifo` returns `-1` which means that something didn't go right. Why would `mkfifo` fail?

here is my code:

```
int main(){

    pid_t pid;
    int rv;
    int fd;

    int fifonum;
    char *fifoName = "toServer2";
    fifonum = mkfifo(fifoName, 0666);

    if (fifonum<0){
        printf("\n unable to create a fifo\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    fd = open(fifoName, O_WRONLY);

    if( (pid=fork()) == -1 )
    {
        printf("fork error, exiting\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(pid){

        printf("this is the parent\n");
        write(fd, "1", sizeof(int));
        close(fd);
        wait(&rv);
        printf("child exited with this status %d\n", rv);

    }else{
        printf("this is the child");
        if(execl("child", "child", NULL)==-1){
            printf("execl error");
            exit(1);
        }   
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **Tip**: Never say that the program is failing for no reason, there must be a reason, you can just say that you can't find the reason, which is by itself a good reason to post a question on SO.

Comment: Use `perror` on failure of `open`, `mkfifo`, and other syscalls. You could also use `strace` on your program. Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: You should give the output of your program as part of the question.

Comment: it gives me error I told him to give me in case of getting -1 from the fifo function - "unable to create fifo". it never even gets to the open function

Comment: the code should check the returned value from : 'fd = open(fifoName, O_WRONLY);' to assure the open was successful

Comment: suggest not opening the fifo until in parent or child, where parent opens for write and child opens for read.

Comment: if this program has EVER run successfully past the mkfifo() statement, then the fifo already exists, so the mkfifo would fail.  suggest first checking, with stat() to determine if the fifo already exists.

Comment: suggest using perror() to output the system call error responses as it will also output the 'errno' value and the related syserror() message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mkfifo` function will fail if the file already exists. One way to avoid the problem is to delete the file before calling `mkfifo`. That way you start with a brand new, empty FIFO each time you run the program.

The general idea is to call `stat` to see if the FIFO file exists, delete the file with `unlink` if it exists, and then call `mkfifo` to make a new FIFO.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int createNewFifo( const char *fifoName )
{
    struct stat stats;
    if ( stat( fifoName, &stats ) < 0 )
    {
        if ( errno != ENOENT )          // ENOENT is ok, since we intend to delete the file anyways
        {
            perror( "stat failed" );    // any other error is a problem
            return( -1 );
        }
    }
    else                                // stat succeeded, so the file exists
    {
        if ( unlink( fifoName ) < 0 )   // attempt to delete the file
        {
            perror( "unlink failed" );  // the most likely error is EBUSY, indicating that some other process is using the file
            return( -1 );
        }
    }

    if ( mkfifo( fifoName, 0666 ) < 0 ) // attempt to create a brand new FIFO
    {
        perror( "mkfifo failed" );
        return( -1 );
    }

    return( 0 );
}

int main( void )
{
    if ( createNewFifo( "toServer2" ) < 0 )
        exit( 1 );

    // do something with the fifo ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think  `fifonum = mkfifo(fifoName, 0666);`will overwrite a FIFO special file if it blocks, check to see if a file named toServer2 all ready exists. (I don't know what your child program does or if it does the clean up for FIFO file.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>




int main(){

    pid_t pid;
    int rv;
    FILE *  fd;
    FILE *  od;

    int fifonum;
    char *fifoName = "toServer2";
    fifonum = mkfifo(fifoName, 0666);

    if (fifonum<0){
        printf("%d\n", fifonum );
        printf("\n unable to create a fifo\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if( (pid=fork()) == -1 )
    {
        printf("fork error, exiting\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    if(pid == 0 ){
        int status;

        fd = fopen(fifoName, "w");
        printf("this is the parent\n");
        fprintf(fd, "3");
        fclose(fd);
        wait(&rv);

        status = remove(fifoName);

        if( status == 0 )
             printf("%s file deleted successfully.\n",fifoName);
        else
        {
        printf("Unable to delete the file\n");
        perror("Error");
        }

    }
    else{

        int c;
        od = fopen(fifoName, "r");
        //fgetc("%d", s);
        c =fgetc(od);
        printf("------%c-------", c );
        fclose(od);



    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Modified your program slightly to pass a 3 from parent process to child process, then clean up the special FIFO file.

Answer (score 0):

"Why would `mkfifo` fail?" Direct from `man 3 mkfifo`:

> ```
>    EACCES One of the directories in pathname did not allow search (execute) permission.
>
>    EEXIST pathname already exists.  This includes the case where pathname is a symbolic link, dangling or not.
>
>    ENAMETOOLONG
>           Either the total length of pathname is greater than PATH_MAX, or an individual filename  component  has  a  length
>           greater  than  NAME_MAX.   In  the GNU system, there is no imposed limit on overall filename length, but some file
>           systems may place limits on the length of a component.
>
>    ENOENT A directory component in pathname does not exist or is a dangling symbolic link.
>
>    ENOSPC The directory or file system has no room for the new file.
>
>    ENOTDIR
>           A component used as a directory in pathname is not, in fact, a directory.
>
>    EROFS  pathname refers to a read-only file system.
> ```

You'll have to check `errno` to find out which of those is the case in your situation (or, as suggested elsewhere, use `perror()`, which will consult `errno` for you and select a suitable text string based on the value).